# Error al subir un archivo al servidor

Tags: html, web, jsp, servidor

Estoy desarrollando un formulario para subir unos datos y un archivo, este archivo quiero guardarlo en una carpeta dentro del proyecto, utilizo enctype="multipart/form-data", pero al momento de rellenar los datos y enviarlos, me bota un error en el servidor, utilizo html para el formulario, jsp para el procesamiento y apache tomcat como servidor.

Este es mi código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Crear Pizza</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid bcontent">
            <form action="crearPizza.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text">Nombre de Pizza</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ingrese nombre">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text">Descripcion</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc" placeholder="Ingrese Descripcion">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text">Precio</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pre" name="pre" placeholder="Ingrese Precio">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fileupload">Imagen</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="img" name="img">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este es mi código jsp //Para procesamiento:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
    String name="", desc="";
    int pre=0;
    String url = "C:\\Users\\Harold\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication1\\web\\img\\menu";
    // Create a factory for disk-based file items
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(1060, new File(url));

// Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = iter.next();

        if (item.isFormField()) {
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("name"))
                name = item.getName();
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("desc"))
                desc = item.getName();
            else `introducir el código aquí`
                pre = Integer.valueOf(item.getName());
        } else {
            File uploadFile = new File(url,item.getName());
            item.write(uploadFile);
        }
    }
%>
```

Y este es el Stacktrace del error

```
Stacktrace:] con causa raÃ­z
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletInputStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:113)
        at org.apache.jsp.autor.crearPizza_jsp._jspService(crearPizza_jsp.java:150)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

He intentado miles de formas en internet y la verdad soy nuevo en esto de programación web, es un proyecto en mi materia de programación, pero no encuentro documentación y lo que encuentro lo aplico y no sirve, como por ejemplo el código que esta en mi página jsp, no se si estoy implementandolo mal, si me hace falta algo o ya de por sí es deprecated, espero puedan colaborarme, ya que no encuentro algo relacionado con lo que estoy usando que pueda utilizar hoy en día, solo encuentro cosas que si investigo algo más me dice que es deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error es muy común en los que apenas estamos iniciando, lo que hay que hacer es importar las librerías `org.apache.commons.fileupload` y `org.apache.commons.io.output` dentro del proyecto y no como comunmente se realiza dentro de la carpeta Java, lib... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Importe la clase `java.io.InputStream` , aquí hay una explicación del tipo de error , https://loquemeinteresadelared.wordpress.com/tag/java-lang-classnotfoundexception/ , y aquí el porqué importar esa clase, https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletInputStream.html , espero que funcione.

Comment: Lo probaré David, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Hola David, ya importé la clase, y me sigue generando el mismo error, que podría hacer?